# PropTypes for react-redux/react-router connect & withRouter functions' ownProps parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a container and a component. The container page ends with the standard (as of `react-router@2.4.x`):

```
export default withRouter(
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(ComponentName)
);
```

In my `mapDispatchToProps` functions I am using the `withRouter` connected router from the `ownProps` parameter in :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, { router }) => ...
```

Is the router something I should be declaring in the `ComponentName.propTypes`, as it isn't actually used IN the component, but in a function that's being created in the container?

I assume so, only because `mapDispatchToProps` is using a `withRouter` generated prop on the component, but was more curious on what the convention is, as removing it doesn't throw any errors on render.

Answer (score -1):

You must use the latest version available. You need to uninstall the old react-router and install the new one.

```
npm uninstall -S react-router

npm i -S react-router@3.0.0-alpha.1
```

Comment: That is in no way related to the question.